# xml request is not created as expected

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl, soapui

Good afternoon,

I'm working on the testing of webservices using the SOAP_UI tool.
I run a script on a web service from its WSDL description in order to have the status of the response of the web service but the request isn't consumed.
I'm supposed to receive the following as result:

```
    <134>1 2024-02-22T12:42:35+01:00 - java - - - com.sagemcom.dc.spain.ws.server.requests.Orders order      [order] idPet 53, format 0, priority 3, fini 20240222124347000W, ffin 20240222124647000W 
<Order xmlns="http://stgdc/ws/B07" IdReq="B07" IdPet="53" Version="4.0">
    <Cnc Id="SAG6300004F92">
        <B07>
        <GENERAL  CheckSTG="N" />
        <MULTI_STG>
            <STG STGid="STG1" PortSTG="8080" ipStg="172.25.0.55" StgProtocol="http" StgPath="/WS_STG/WS_STG.asmx" nRetryWS="3" tRetryWS="30" toutWS="10"   FtpProtocol="FTP" DestDirReport="/cycles" ipFtp="172.25.0.55" nRetryFtp="5" tRetryFtp="300" toutFtp="300" FtpRandomDelay="100" FtpUserReport="hola" FtpPwdReport="hola"  ipFtpDCUpg="172.25.0.55" UserFtpDCUpg="DCUPGRADE" PwdFtpDCUpg=""  ipFtpMeterUpg="172.25.0.55" UserFtpMeterUpg="CNTUPGRADE" PwdFtpMeterUpg="" />
            <STG STGid="STG2" PortSTG="8030" ipStg="192.168.1.35" StgProtocol="http" StgPath="/WS_STG/WS_STG.asmx" nRetryWS="1" tRetryWS="30" toutWS="10"   FtpProtocol="FTP" DestDirReport="/downloads" ipFtp="192.168.1.35" nRetryFtp="0" tRetryFtp="1" toutFtp="1" FtpRandomDelay="0" FtpUserReport="hola" FtpPwdReport="hola"  ipFtpDCUpg="192.168.1.35" UserFtpDCUpg="DCUPGRADE" PwdFtpDCUpg=""  ipFtpMeterUpg="192.168.1.35" UserFtpMeterUpg="CNTUPGRADE" PwdFtpMeterUpg="" />
        </MULTI_STG>
        <EVENTS  SpontSTGDest="4" />
        </B07>
    </Cnc>
</Order>
```

Any idea about the source of the block please?

I created the folowing request:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="urn:stgdc/dc/ws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:Order>
         <ws:IdPet>111</ws:IdPet>
         <ws:Format>0</ws:Format>
         <ws:Order>xmlns="http://stgdc/ws/B07" IdReq="B07" Version="4.0"&lt;Cnc Id="SAG6300004F92"&lt;B07>&lt;GENERAL  CheckSTG="N" />&lt;MULTI_STG>&lt;STG STGid="STG1" PortSTG="8080" ipStg="172.25.0.55" StgProtocol="http" StgPath="/WS_STG/WS_STG.asmx" nRetryWS="3" tRetryWS="30" toutWS="10"   FtpProtocol="FTP" DestDirReport="/cycles" ipFtp="172.25.0.55" nRetryFtp="5" tRetryFtp="300" toutFtp="300" FtpRandomDelay="100" FtpUserReport="hola" FtpPwdReport="hola"  ipFtpDCUpg="172.25.0.55" UserFtpDCUpg="DCUPGRADE" PwdFtpDCUpg=""  ipFtpMeterUpg="172.25.0.55" UserFtpMeterUpg="CNTUPGRADE" PwdFtpMeterUpg="" />&lt;/MULTI_STG>&lt;EVENTS  SpontSTGDest="4" />&lt;/B07>&lt;/Cnc>></ws:Order>
         <ws:Fini>20240226154024000W</ws:Fini>
         <ws:Ffin>20240226154824000W</ws:Ffin>
         <ws:Priority>1</ws:Priority>
      </ws:Order>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But i got the followings results:

```
    <134>1 2024-02-26T17:35:49+01:00 - java - - - com.sagemcom.dc.spain.ws.server.requests.Orders order     [order] idPet 111, format 0, priority 1, fini 20240226154024000W, ffin 20240226154824000W
xmlns="http://stgdc/ws/B07" IdReq="B07" Version="4.0"<Cnc Id="SAG6300004F92"<B07><GENERAL  CheckSTG="N" /><MULTI_STG><STG STGid="STG1" PortSTG="8080" ipStg="172.25.0.55" StgProtocol="http" StgPath="/WS_STG/WS_STG.asmx" nRetryWS="3" tRetryWS="30" toutWS="10"   FtpProtocol="FTP" DestDirReport="/cycles" ipFtp="172.25.0.55" nRetryFtp="5" tRetryFtp="300" toutFtp="300" FtpRandomDelay="100" FtpUserReport="hola" FtpPwdReport="hola"  ipFtpDCUpg="172.25.0.55" UserFtpDCUpg="DCUPGRADE" PwdFtpDCUpg=""  ipFtpMeterUpg="172.25.0.55" UserFtpMeterUpg="CNTUPGRADE" PwdFtpMeterUpg="" /></MULTI_STG><EVENTS  SpontSTGDest="4" /></B07></Cnc>>
<135>1 2024-02-26T17:35:49+01:00 - java - - - sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl logReply    POST /WS_DC/WS_DC.asmx HTTP/1.1 [200  OK] ()
<13>1 2024-02-26T17:35:49+01:00 - pik - - - [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
<131>1 2024-02-26T17:35:49+01:00 - java - - - com.sagemcom.dc.spain.ws.server.requests.OrdersParsingThread run
com.sagemcom.scheduler.spain.orders.InvalidOrderException: Invalid xml org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog. (5)
        at com.sagemcom.dc.spain.ws.server.requests.OrdersParsingThread.createOrderTask(OrdersParsingThread.java:145)
        at com.sagemcom.dc.spain.ws.server.requests.OrdersParsingThread.run(OrdersParsingThread.java:116)
```

Comment: Try removing the Order line in the SOAP and then see if you get any return.  I believe the error is in the Order and removing will help isolate the issue.

Comment: @jdweng after moving the line that contains "ws:Order" , it display 500 internal server

Comment: Great.  Error 500 says that the connection completed successfully and the error is when the contents is being processed.  It eliminates lots of other issues.   I would go to server and check Event Viewer to see if there are and errors when the connection is made.   You could slowly add back the missing element without the attributes and then add back the attributes one at a time to try to isolate issues.  It may be the 500 is occurring because the Order Element is missing.

Comment: @jdweng As verified, The 500 is occurring because the Order Element is missing. And same issue: :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. What does means this issue exactly please?

Comment: Where did you get the Order tag format?  Can't find an example on the web.  I think you are using a Sagemcom Modem but cannot find any documentation for making a Soap Request.

Comment: it's fixed. Thanks @jdweng. It's about adding the two lines &lt;Order and &lt;/Order> at the end of the order.